# How to split an array by a condition on adjacent elements into a limited number of partitions

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

Let's say I have an array of numbers, e.g.

```
ary = [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 11, 13, 7, 24]
```

I would like to split the array between the first point where a smaller number follows a larger one. My output should be:

```
[[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

I've tried `slice_when` and it comes quite close:

```
ary.slice_when { |i, j| i > j }.to_a
#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13], [7, 24]]
```

But it also splits between `13` and `7`, so I have to join the remaining arrays:

```
first, *rest = ary.slice_when { |i, j| i > j }.to_a
[first, rest.flatten(1)]
#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

which looks a bit cumbersome. It also seems inefficient to keep comparing items when the match was already found.

I am looking for a general solution based on an arbitrary condition. Having numeric elements and `i > j` is just an example.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Just so I understand, should it only slice on the first occurrence and not the latter?

Comment: @Anthony yes exactly. That's why I would like to avoid `slice_when`. Slicing the array into multiple parts just to undo everything but the first one doesn't feel right.

Comment: Gotta say, I actually think your initial approach is pretty elegant @Stefan

Comment: @SRack well, the code is short. But the algorithm keeps comparing every pair of elements, although it could stop at the first match, which seems inefficient (what if the array is huge?). Just like `array.select { ... }.first` when you simply want `array.find { ... }`

Comment: Very good point! Thanks for the response.

Comment: To join the remaining arrays appending `.partition.with_index { |_,i| i.zero? }.map(&:flatten)` is an option, but probably better ways.

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you leave a comment as to what is wrong with my question, please?

Comment: @Stefan Maybe someone fat-fingered it, there's no confirmation required on down-votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more alternative:

```
index = ary.each_cons(2).find_index { |i, j| i > j }
[ary[0..index], ary[index + 1..-1]]
#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

I believe space is O(n) and time is O(n)

Benchmark:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
             anthony    63.941k i/100ms
             steve_t    98.000  i/100ms
              tadman   123.000  i/100ms
              sergio    75.477k i/100ms
               hoffm   101.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
             anthony    798.456k (± 4.0%) i/s -      4.028M in   5.053175s
             steve_t    985.736  (± 5.0%) i/s -      4.998k in   5.083188s
              tadman      1.229k (± 4.1%) i/s -      6.150k in   5.010877s
              sergio    948.357k (± 3.7%) i/s -      4.755M in   5.020931s
               hoffm      1.013k (± 2.9%) i/s -      5.151k in   5.089890s

Comparison:
              sergio:   948357.4 i/s
             anthony:   798456.2 i/s - 1.19x  slower
              tadman:     1229.5 i/s - 771.35x  slower
               hoffm:     1012.9 i/s - 936.30x  slower
             steve_t:      985.7 i/s - 962.08x  slower
```

code for the benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def anthony(ary)
  index = ary.each_cons(2).find_index { |i, j| i > j }
  [ary[0..index], ary[index + 1..-1]]
end

def steve_t(ary)
  break_done = false
  ary.slice_when { |i, j| (break_done = i > j) unless break_done }.to_a
end

def tadman(ary)
  ary.each_with_object([[],[]]) do |v, a|
    a[a[1][-1] ? 1 : (a[0][-1]&.>(v) ? 1 : 0)] << v
  end
end

def sergio(ary)
  break_point = ary.each_cons(2).with_index do |(a, b), idx|
    break idx if b < a # plug your block here
  end + 1

  [
    ary.take(break_point),
    ary.drop(break_point)
  ]
end

def split(ary)
  split_done = false
  ary.chunk_while do |i, j|
    split_done || !(split_done = yield(i, j))
  end.to_a
end

def hoffm(ary)
  split(ary) { |i, j| i > j }
end

ary = Array.new(10_000) { rand(1..100) }
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  # Configure the number of seconds used during
  # the warmup phase (default 2) and calculation phase (default 5)
  x.config(:time => 5, :warmup => 2)

  # Typical mode, runs the block as many times as it can
  x.report("anthony") { anthony(ary) }
  x.report("steve_t") { steve_t(ary) }
  x.report("tadman") { tadman(ary) }
  x.report("sergio") { sergio(ary) }
  x.report("hoffm") { hoffm(ary) }

    # Compare the iterations per second of the various reports!
  x.compare!
end
```

Fascinating that `#take` and `#drop` from @sergio's answer is slightly faster than `Array#[range..range]`, they both use the same c method underneath so I can't explain it.

Comment: You can use `find_index { ... }` instead of `to_a.index { ... }`

Comment: Of course, `Enumerable#find_index`. What was I thinking? :)

Comment: @Stefan: it seems that your ideal solution is shaping up :)

Comment: I like this. Extracting two fixed-size arrays should also be faster than appending the elements one by one (`slice_when` relies on `each`.)

Comment: Seems like processing the range adds some overhead. Passing two arguments to `Array#[]` is faster, i.e. `ary[0, index + 1]` and `ary[index + 1, ary.length]` (the length is adjusted automatically)

Comment: What if the array were `[1,2,3]`?

Answer (score 10):

There's probably a better way to do this but my first thought is...

```
break_done = false
ary.slice_when { |i, j| (break_done = i > j) unless break_done }.to_a
#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

Comment: Any chance to get rid of the temporary variable?

Comment: I did try to work around that... initializing the variable in the block it doesn't persist through iterations. :(

Comment: You can monkey patch it into the Array class: `class Array; def slice_when_once; break_done = false; slice_when { |i, j| break_done = yield(i, j) unless break_done }; end; end;`. Then you can do: `ary.slice_when_once { |i, j| i > j }.to_a`.

Comment: If you don't like to smudge the default classes you can also create a module for the helper method, and extend the object: `ary.extend(EnumExtensions).slice_when_once { |i, j| i > j }.to_a`.

Comment: I came up with `f = false; ary.slice_when { |i, j| !f && f ||= i > j }.to_a` which is pretty much the same idea, only avoiding the `unless`.

Comment: I like! Alternatively, `break_not_done = true` followed by `break_not_done && break_not_done = i <= j`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you'll find this more elegant, but it prevents the split-and-rejoin maneuver:

```
def split(ary)
  split_done = false
  ary.slice_when do |i, j|
    !split_done && (split_done = yield(i, j))
  end.to_a
end
```

Usage:

```
ary = [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 11, 13, 7, 24]    
split(ary){ |i, j| i > j }
#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

---

**Update**:

Some may find this variant more readable. `#chunk_while` is the inverse of `#split_when` and then I just applied De Morgan's Law to the block.

```
def split(ary)
  split_done = false
  ary.chunk_while do |i, j|
    split_done || !(split_done = yield(i, j))
  end.to_a
end
```

Comment: that is the longer version of @SteveTurczyn answer :|

Comment: Ah, he posted as I was writing mine. Mine is a bit more general as it provides a function that takes an arbitrary comparison condition as a block.

Comment: Guess it serves me right for taking the time to do it test-first. ;)

Comment: Actually, I like this better as the temporary variable is confined to the scope of the method.  Also could be implemented as a patch to Array class.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another version. Not particularly elegant <strike>or efficient</strike>, but is quite efficient (*see comments*).

```
break_point = ary.each_cons(2).with_index do |(a, b), idx|
  break idx if b < a # plug your block here
end + 1

[
  ary.take(break_point), 
  ary.drop(break_point)
] # => [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

Comment: seems that this could be reduced to `each_cons(2).find_index { |a,b| b < a } + 1` since your break is essentially what `find_index` does

Comment: @Anthony: yay! :)

Comment: @engineersmnky: indeed, didn't remember about `find_index` at the time. But if I change it, it'd duplicate at least two other answers :)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be as hard a problem as it's proving to be. The `slice_when` doesn't take a maximum number of slices as an argument, but if it did it'd be easy.

Here's one optimized around two partitions:

```
def slice_into_two(ary)
  ary.each_with_object([[],[]]) do |v, a|
    a[a[1][-1] ? 1 : (a[0][-1]&.>(v) ? 1 : 0)] << v
  end
end
```

Comment: You could use `each_with_object` to get rid of that stray `a`.

Comment: @Stefan A good optimization there on this iteration of it, adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Or, if you want to use yield to pass a custom block: `a[a[1][-1] ? 1 : (a[0][-1]  && yield(a[0][-1], v) ? 1 : 0)] << v`, so you can: `slice_into_two(ary) { |i, j| i > j }`

Answer (score 2):

#### First approach

Just thought I'd post this way, an enumerator within an enumerator creating a partition. The first *if-branch* is (as others such as tadman have implemented) in case of an empty array.

```
arr = [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 11, 13, 7, 24]

Enumerator.new { |y|
  if arr.empty?
    y << []
  else
    enum = arr.each
    a = enum.next

    #collect elements until rule is broken
    arr1 = loop.with_object([a]) { |_,o|
      break o if enum.peek < a
      o << a = enum.next
    }

    #collect remainder of elements
    arr2 = loop.with_object([]) { |_,o| o << enum.next }

    #incase the rule is never met; just return arr's elements
    arr2 == [] ? arr.each { |e| y << e } : y << arr1; y << arr2

}.entries

#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

#### Second approach

This is somewhat derived from tadman's approach i.e. the partition is predefined and emptied and filled appropriately.

```
arr = [1, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 11, 13, 7, 24]

loop.with_object([[],arr.dup]) { |_,o|
  if o.last == []
    break o
  elsif o.last[0] < o.last[1]
    o.first << o.last.shift
  else
    o.first << o.last.shift
    break o
  end
}

#=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

Looping through the array (albeit a duplicate), returning a partitioned array as soon as the rule is broken.

Comment: I think the way I'm dealing with an empty array is a bit clumsy but hey ho. Using loops was interesting enough though.

Answer (score 2):

```
first, *last = ary
first = [first]
while last.any? && first.last <= last.first do
  first << last.shift 
end
[first, last]
  #=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

Another way:

```
f = ary.lazy.slice_when { |i, j| i > j }.first
  #=> [1, 3, 6, 7, 10] 
[f, ary[f.size..-1]]
  #=> [[1, 3, 6, 7, 10], [9, 11, 13, 7, 24]]
```

Comment: `first.last <= last.first` nice one :-)